# How Laravel 4.2 detects sessionId?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a Laravel 4.2 web app running under a reverse proxy. I observe that `Session Id` (`Session::getId()`) changes randomly when user login to the system, but the `PHPSESSID` didn't change.

I wonder why somehow Laravel `Session Id` is affected by the proxy but `PHPSESSID` does not (because everything runs very well without the proxy set up). I digged into the framework but I didn't figure out the root cause yet. How can `Illuminate\Session\Store` manage to get the `Session ID`?

Comment: Laravel implements it's own session handler, it does not use the native PHP session management (so no `start_session`, `PHPSESSID` cookie, etc). It generates it's own session ID and writes it, encrypted, into a cookie named `laravel_session` (but that name can be modified in `app/config/session.php`).